# Default Html page on select tag - Angular js

Tags: angularjs

When the html page loads I need to load the default `tableView.html` which is present in the views folder. This is not working

But when I change the drop down "Table View" or "List View" it works.

The problem I think is that if I am giving

```
$scope.employeeView = 'tableView.html';
```

then the Table View will be shown in default when the page loads.

But how can I call a html page inside a folder.

I am attaching the code

Thanks in advance.

```js
$scope.employeeView = 'views/tableView.html';
```

```html
<div id="tableView">
    <label for="selectView">Select View</label>
     <select id="selectView" ng-model="employeeView">
      <option value="views/listView.html">List View</option> 
      <option value="views/tableView.html">Table View</option> 
     </select>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div ng-include="employeeView"></div>
```

Initially

```js
$scope.employeeView = '/views/tableView.html';
```

```html
<div id="tableView">
    <label for="selectView">Select View</label>
     <select id="selectView" ng-model="employeeView">
      <option value="views/tableView.html">Table View</option>
      <option value="views/listView.html">List View</option>
     </select>
   </div>
```

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6AQi.png)

Comment: Do you mean `$scope.employeeView = 'views/tableView.html'`?

Comment: Also here is working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/2pyJvBuUOPZPkqK0DXcM?p=preview so check if its something else

Comment: yes  i need to show the tableView.html  page when page loads , but changing the view  table or list it should reflect. The Problem is that  table view and list view  html pages are inside Views folder
So if i give $scope.employeeView = ''views/tableView.html . Its not showing  but when i change values in select tag its working.
 I am new  to angular js

Comment: I had already done that one, but inside a folder it's not working   $scope.employeeView = 'views/tableView.html'

Comment: i have attached the folder structure below the code snippet

Comment: did you try set root: '/views/tableView.html'

Comment: no.I am new to angular. are you mentioning about the $location injector.

Comment: yeah , its my mistake  the question itself is correct. Sorry Maxim, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since i was  running in my local machine on chrome Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes . So the view wasn't showing. But the code was correct.
$scope.employeeView = 'views/tableView.html';